# I am trying to user Swing in Eclipse but I keep getting this error. See below

Tags: java, eclipse, swing

```
private void initialize() {
        frame = new JFrame();
        frame.setBounds(100, 100, 450, 300);
        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        JLabel lblSomeText = new JLabel("Hello, World!");
        frame.getContentPane().add(lblSomeText, BorderLayout.CENTER); //error here

    }
```

It says: "The Type container is not visible around the frame.getContentPane()"

Comment: Are you missing an import? Maybe you have a private variable?

Comment: Yes, you have probably messed up your imports.  Please show us the entire file, including imports.  This small snipette is not enough to resolve the problem.

Comment: p.s. Never NEVER call `setBounds()`.  Especially if you are new.  It messes things up, just let your layout manager do that for you.

Comment: Is that the exact wording of the error you’re getting?  If it isn’t, please edit your question, and copy and paste the exact error into it.

Answer (score 1):

The following complete code works for me.  Please check your imports and show us your entire code so we can help you!

```
package stackoverflow;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class SwingTest {

   public static void main( String[] args ) {
      JFrame frame = new JFrame();

      JLabel lblSomeText = new JLabel( "Hello, World!" );
      frame.getContentPane().add( lblSomeText );

      frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
      frame.setSize( 640, 480 );  // use setSize() instead of setBounds
//      frame.pack();             // or call pack() instead
      frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
      frame.setVisible( true );
   }

}
```